# How to find invalid doc inside an index in Elasticsearch 6.8.x while getting "type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string: \"\u00000\"

Tags: java, elasticsearch, error-handling, response, restore

I'm doing a restore request from a cluster with elasticsearch 5.6.9 to another cluster with elasticsearch 6.8.9 on lots of indices, but there's one problematic index that I can not 
perform the restore on it, and I get this error message back from elasticsearch:
`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[PROD-master-elasticsearch2-26-i-0adce4e9cd69bc599][172.18.21.70:9300][cluster:admin/snapshot/restore]"}],"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string: \"\u00000\""},"status":400}`

I'm trying to figure out how to find what is invalid in this index, maybe there's a problematic doc inside it? when using _search to look inside the index I don't find this "\u00000\" thing.

Any ideas on how to deal with this issue? how to find which doc is damaged inside the index? why is it happening in the first place? And what can I do in the source cluster with this index so that the next time I'm restoring it to my target destination it will be all right?

If anyone has any knowledge about that issue and can shed any light on this it would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Did you push the mappings or you let es automap it? Could you check it ?

Comment: @Yotam can you please share the mapping of your index, `\u00000 ` means `NULL`  so it means you are passing a string which consist of `null` to a integer field in your index, hence getting a number format exception

Comment: http://esip:9200/yourindex/_mappings/ then http://esip:9200/yournewindex/_mappings/

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Amit I thought so too but another thing I think is that it is a general problem with cluster masters as I can't even delete a random snapshot from all my snapshots on that cluster, as it throws the same error, so not sure if it's related.

Comment: a new thing I've discovered it happens only when doing the restore from Elasticsearch 5.x to Elasticsearch 6.x. I'm still investigating this issue hope this will lead to some conclusion. Any ideas?